# Haskell beginners array creation

Tags: haskell

I have been struggling with a rather simple thing in Haskell and since I cannot understand what is and why is blocking me I though it would be a good idea to ask here. I would like to create a function that deletes numbers in a given array that are exactly the same as the previous one was. So, for example, from array: `[12,12,3,4,5,5,5,7,9]` I would like to get an output of: `[12,3,4,5,7,9]`. Based on that I wrote:

```
removeDuplicates[x]                  = x
removeDuplicates(x:y:ys) | x == y    = removeDuplicates(x:ys)
                         | otherwise = x ++ removeDuplicates([]:y:ys)
```

... but after succesfully loading the code I get an error of:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a. (Eq a, Num [a]) => [a]
```

I understand there is something wrong with my `otherwise` statement and type of returned value, but since I am a total beginner in Haskell I don't know how to solve this rather funny than serious problem.

Comment: `x ++ removeDuplicates([]:y:ys)` should be either `[x] ++ removeDuplicates([]:y:ys)` or, better, `x : removeDuplicates([]:y:ys)`. Note also that you haven't handled the case of the empty list: an extra case `removeDuplicates [] = []` will cover this.

Comment: I get an error that: `x : removeDuplicates([]:y:ys) ` cannot construct the infinite type `a ~ [a]`.

Comment: oh there's also an error on your first line, it should be `removeDuplicates[x] = [x]`

Comment: the key point is that you need your function - in all cases - to return a list, and the `x`, `y` etc in your pattern matches aren't (necessarily) lists, they're elements of the list.

Comment: `removeDuplicates []                   = []
removeDuplicates [x]                  = [x]
removeDuplicates (x:y:ys) | x == y    = removeDuplicates (x:ys)
                          | otherwise = x : removeDuplicates ([]:y:ys)` with this kind of code I still get same error as in the beggining :/

Comment: Ok, solved it by transforming `removeDuplicates ([]:y:ys)` into `removeDuplicates (y:ys)`. Thanks for help and hints :)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I missed that error - well done on finding it yourself

Comment: Even if you found the answer yourself, you can still write up the answer below, so it might help someone else in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer